# Date still in Core Data app after I delete the .sqlite files

Tags: swift, core-data

I have (finally) managed to get prototype app using Core Data to persist to an sqlite file. Quitting and restarting I see the same data. So all seems well.

I want to now start from scratch again so I went to delete the sqlite persisted data. I set up it's location as :

```
    open lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
      // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
      let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
      return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
    }()

    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("TrainingDiary.sqlite")
```

which places the .sqlite files in ~/Library/Containers/uk.me.stevenlord.Core-Data-Binding/Data/Documents

There are four files in there: iChats, TrainingDiary.sqlite, TrainingDiary.sqlite-shm and TrainingDiary.sqlite-wal

I close my app. Delete all there files. When I reopen my app the full Core Data model is still there and when I look back in this directory the files are back.

What am I missing ?

EDIT:
I've figured out whats happening though I still don't quite understand why this is how it works. The above code specifies where the Core Data should be saved:
which places the .sqlite files in

```
~/Library/Containers/uk.me.stevenlord.Core-Data-Binding/Data/Documents/TrainingDiary.sqlite
```

This it does however I've now found that the app also saves the following

```
~/Library/Containers/uk.me.stevenlord.Core-Data-Binding/Data/Library/Application Support/Core Data Binding/Core_Data_Binding.sqlite
```

My XCode9 project is called "Core Data Binding". If I delete this file and start up my app I get an app with no data as expected.

So the persistent store is not going to where I specified. So still confused.

I'm missing something still. But something different

Comment: It's hard to say but it might help to see the code where you set up Core Data and the code where you delete the files.

Comment: The core data is set up through a GUI using Cocoa Bindings. I haven't created any core data direct in code. Rather I've linked up add and delete buttons to an Array Controller. I'm not trying to delete this in code I'm trying to just completely remove the persistent store from my file system so I can start again from scratch. I've figured out how to delete in code but this in now very frustrating as I don't understand whats happening. I've set the place to persist the Core Data and I see it being placed there but if I delete those files my app still manages to load up the data.